# Use apple automator to open a pdf in acrobat and enter keystroke on the dialog that pops up when I run acrobat

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to use Automator on my mac to get around a system dialog. When I open a pdf I get this dialog from acrobat for which I always want to select deny:
[image: Acrobat Dialogue]

I made an automator app that works to select deny, but when I change the application that opens pdf's to this automator.app it doesn't actually open the document, it just launches acrobat and selects deny on the dialog then just sits there.
The way I'd like it to work is that I want to double click any pdf on my computer and always select deny on this dialog which always pops up whenever acrobat opens up.
I'm not married to accomplishing this the way I'm doing it now, I just don't know how else to do it.
The current automator steps/flow is this:
[image]

Comment: Also I've tried deleting the entry for this in keychain access and removing access but it still keeps asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found how to do this in a slightly different way for anyone interested. Just using the Watch Me Do function instead since it always pops up the same way. Then I just saved it as an app and I right clicked a pdf file and selected this custom app as the one to always use when opening pdf files.
[image]